# Java java.nio writes line of []s

Tags: java, nio

I am using java.nio to copy a file, it copies fine except for the fact that there is a line of []s at the end of the file.

Here is my code:

```
source (the source channel)
source.read(buffer);
buffer.flip();
mbb.put(buffer)
mbb is MappedByteBuffer
```

Source Channel:

```
source = new FileInputStream(original(this is a File)).getChannel();
```

MappedByteBuffer:

```
source.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, 1024);
```

Comment: It looks like you've passed in a byte array (or something) which contained a number of 'null bytes' at the end.

I think you need to provide more of your code: how are you constructing the source channel and `MappedByteBuffer` ?

(also, I think you mean `MappedByteBuffer` not `MappedByteArray`)

Comment: @amir75, yeah that was a typo, it's actually `MappedByteBuffer`. Added what you said above.

Comment: That little square at the end of the file is probably a unicode character you were unable to identify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assuming the file is 1024 bytes long instead of using the actual file size. I suspect the junk is in the MappedByteBuffer rather than the file.

Comment: Yes, I'm not using `Buffer.allocateDirect()`